# Integrate Gutenberg as a Standalone App

Tags: block-editor

I'm thinking about integrating the new awesome WordPress block editor (Gutenberg) outside of its environment (WordPress core), so is there any way to get just the text editor code and use it for example in another CMS or framework or just a simple HTML page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, You can use Gutenberg as a standalone app or CMS agnostic app. Drupal using Gutenberg as a npm module and then integrating in their own CMS. [Drupal Gutenberg](https://www.drupal.org/project/gutenberg) is decoupling Gutenberg from WordPress and using as JS editor [Gutenberg JS](https://github.com/front/gutenberg-js). This way, developers can build block for Gutenberg  and port it to two different CMS.

Comment: do you know how I can change Gutenberg JS to another language using l10n (out of wordpress core of course)?

Comment: Sorry mate, can't help you with that.